# Is an expansion of the US Supreme Court really possible?

Tags: united-states, supreme-court, republican-party, democratic-party

With the confirmation of Amy Coney Barrett, the idea of expanding the US Supreme Court has caught fire among some Democrats. With a 6-3 conservative majority on the court, prominent progressive Democrats like Representative Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez argue that if Democrats win this election term, they should seriously consider increasing the number of justices. In this context, is an expansion of the US Supreme Court really possible?

Assuming Democrats control the presidency, senate, and house in 2021, what can Republican legislators do to stop a SCOTUS expansion?

Comment: The Supreme Court's size is set by legislation, not the Constitution. Its initial size was set to 6 in 1789, and changed sizes several times between then and 1869 (including court sizes of 7, 9, and 10 justices) before settling to it current size of 9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming Democrats do not have 60 votes in the Senate, Republicans can [filibuster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filibuster_in_the_United_States_Senate) any legislation to increase the size of the court.

Legislation is required to change the size of the court, as discussed via the [various acts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States#Size_of_the_court) used to change it in the past.

> The size of the Court was first altered by an 1801 act which would have reduced the size of the court to five members upon its next vacancy, but an 1802 act promptly negated the 1801 act, legally restoring the court's size to six members before any such vacancy occurred. As the nation's boundaries grew, Congress added justices to correspond with the growing number of judicial circuits: seven in 1807, nine in 1837, and ten in 1863.[76]

Democrats could then respond by removing the Filibuster (which would only require a bare 51 vote majority) and passing the legislation anyway. As suggested here by [Harry Reid](https://apnews.com/article/election-2020-joe-biden-filibusters-legislation-only-on-ap-d85c3f63df1c6e71f39d2f7063503d81). Though not in relation to this particular legislation.

> “We should give the Republicans a little bit of time, to see if they’re going to work with him,” he said. “But the time’s going to come when he’s going to have to move in and get rid of the filibuster.”

Comment: probably worth specifying a *three fifths* supermajority. Strictly speaking 51% is a supermajority, but not sufficient to defeat a filibuster

Comment: 51% is a majority, not a supermajority. As far as I can tell, supermajority means something stronger than simply a majority, typically when it exceeds some level required to approve some action (e.g. 2/3, 3/5, 3/4)

Comment: @eques I think the point is that 51% is more than the smallest possible majority (e.g. 50 out of 99 is less than 51%) so 51% is strictly speaking a supermajority. In theory a legislature could demand a supermajority of 51% instead of the normal majority of more than 50%, though it would be pretty silly. So the word supermajority is pretty meaningless unless you clarify the percentage required.

Comment: @FrederikVds I think someone has edited the supermajority term out of the answer for me. But Wikipedia defines it as [requirement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermajority) for a level of support greater than 1/2. In the Senate context I was thinking of that would be 60 votes (3/5th assuming no vacancies) cloture rules, but obviously in other contexts it may vary

Comment: @FrederikVds In the particular case of the Senate, 51% is the actually the smallest majority (50/100 is not a majority) so it's hardly "super". In the broader use of the term, 51% would be extremely unlikely to ever be a "threshold" amount for a supermajority since unless a body has more than 200 people for there to be a difference between simple majority and a 51% "supermajority".

Comment: @eques No, 51% is not the smallest majority in the US Senate, as I already said a majority of 50/99 is smaller than 51/100. And I don't think his point was that 51% was likely to ever be picked as a requirement for a supermajority, it was a reductio ad absurdum to point out that more explanation was needed than just the word "supermajority." A lack of realism is the point of a reductio ad absurdum.

Comment: @FrederikVds How many seats are in the full Senate? 100, not 99. My point was there is nothing "super" about the first level above 50% in any body -- it's only a majority then. The remainder of your comment doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @eques I get your point, but it's simply false. 51% is not the "first level above 50%", 50.5% is, corresponding to 50 out of 99 senators. 51% is indeed the smallest possible majority when all senators are present, but that's irrelevant, most votes don't take place with all senators present. The rest of my comment explained that he's not saying "strictly speaking 51% is a supermajority" because he believes such a requirement would be likely, but to show that the word "supermajority" is unnecessarily vague. So your argument about a 51% requirement being unlikely is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @FrederikVds my initial comment was in response to Tristan's "strictly speaking 51% is a supermajority" which is definitely not the case. To define "super" as "more than bare minimum" seems a stretch of the word. The "first level" may have been imprecise. My point was the difference between simple majority and 51% is for many bodies impractically small (e.g. for the Senate it amounts to *1* vote).

Comment: @eques That's what "strictly speaking" means, it means "without any relaxation of standards or precision". So while you usually wouldn't call a 51% majority a supermajority, it fits the definition of "greater than the threshold of more than one-half used for a majority" if you take that definition strictly. He gave an absurd example of something that is technically a supermajority even though nobody would intuitively consider it one, to point out that the word supermajority is too vague and needed clarification. You keep saying he used the word in an absurd way but that was exactly the point.

Comment: My exact point is that "Strictly speaking" 51% is NOT a supermajority. The definition of a supermajority is not "greater than the threshold of more than one half" (i.e. a supermajority is not any majority which is not the minimum majority).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115655/discussion-between-frederikvds-and-eques).

Answer (score 13):

Sure, they can.

The last time this subject came up was 1937, with [President Franklin Roosevelt](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/roosevelt-announces-court-packing-plan).

The Supreme Court had struck down a good portion of his New Deal as unconstitutional. As a result, Roosevelt put forth a plan to expand the SC to 15 judges, which would give him six new appointees... enough to reverse the decisions that did not go in his favor.

However, this was opposed and shot down by the Senate.

And in the end, it was unnecessary. By 1942, the majority of justices were appointed by Roosevelt, and the industrialization of the war made the parts of his New Deal shot down by the court, superfluous.

Comment: I'm not sure the FDR comparison is valid. While I'm not familiar with all the aspects, your link says it never came to a vote before congress. And crucially it was opposed by members of his own party. Functionally it does not speak to what the minority party can do to prevent similar changes that enjoy the backing of the  majority party in the Senate.

Comment: My point is: Congress can change the number of Supreme Court judges, and it has been contemplated in the past. The Roosevelt experience is a valid comparison: the nation did not have the political will to allow this, as expressed by members of his own party.

Answer (score 9):

There is little that Republicans in Congress would be able to do to block the change in the law that would be required.  While Republicans can attempt to do a filibuster, the [nuclear option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_option) can be used by the Democrats to override the 60-vote requirement.

The only thing that Republicans can really do about this kind of legislation is to challenge its constitutionality in the courts.  Such a challenge would, inevitably, get to the Supreme Court, and it's unclear how many of the vacancies created by this legislation would be filled (and thus have a pro-liberal majority rather than a pro-conservative majority) by the time it got there.  Of course, even if none of the newly-created seats are filled, there is no guarantee that such a challenge would be successful.

Comment: What kind of legislation are you envisioning being challenged in the courts? Are you proposing that the Supreme Court could overrule congress on the size and makeup of the court?

Comment: Yes, with the word "could" doing some heavy lifting in that sentence.  If (and that's a big if) the Supreme Court rules that the legislation expanding the court is unconstitutional, then it's struck off the statute book.

Comment: It's hard to imagine how such a law could run afoul of the constitution.  Do you have any example of a provision that might be struck down?  How is a law saying that there are ten or twelve associate justices unconstitutional when a law saying that there are eight isn't?  Who would even have standing to challenge the law in the first place?

Comment: Since the Republicans have repeatedly expanded *state* Supreme Courts, I doubt they could make a case on the *federal* level.

Comment: I've clarified my answer to state that I am not opining on how likely a constitutional challenge is to be successful.

Comment: @MartinSchröder "The Republicans have done one thing and argued the complete opposite when convenient for them" is the precise reason that that we're discussing this in the first place.

Comment: @phoog that's for the court to decide. If they decide that, say, Article IV Section 4 says it can't be done, it would be no more bizarre than other interpretations they've made in the past, and there would be no authority to appeal to.

Comment: @hobbs Congress could impeach the justices. Although we're starting to get in dangerously hypothetic scenarios, it's technically possible.

Comment: @JSLavertu It would need a 2/3 Senate majority to convict and remove a Supreme Court justice. The Democrats are never going to have 67 Senate seats (the Republicans might, due to the Senate’s institutional bias towards small rural states).

Comment: The last time any party won a 2/3 majority in the Senate was in 1964 (D).

Comment: @hobbs who would sue?  The case is unlikely to make it to trial in _any_ court, much less the supreme court.  And the court is not going to precipitate the constitutional crisis that would result if they invalidated the law changing the word "eight" to "ten" or "twelve" or any other number, especially not by citing irrelevant parts of the constitution like article 4 section 4.  The court wants to preserve its legitimacy, which that would not.

Comment: @MikeScott As I said: *technically* possible. Obviously, not gonna happen in today's political climate.

Comment: @phoog It absolutely runs afoul of the _intent_ of the Constitution. There's not even a question about that. So then, the decision comes down to whether the justices would rule to follow strictly the wording of the Constitution (which allows packing) or its original intent (which is obviously not for the court to be stacked by political hacks whenever one party or the other gets the Presidency + a Senate majority.) The judicial branch is designed to be independent and provide a check on the power of the executive and legislative branches, not to be a rubber stamp for them.

Comment: @phoog A majority of states could sue. GOP members of Congress could sue. Independent conservative-leaning legal organizations could sue. Random citizens could sue. Reasonable theories of standing could be made for any of those, since the Supreme Court affects everyone.

Comment: @phoog Consider, for example, that even the conservative-leaning court recently struck down Trump's _ending_ of the DACA program. The DACA program was created by executive order. It is very clearly within executive power to end it, even if it isn't so clear that it was within executive power to start it in the first place. However, the court ruled that the _reason for_ ending it was arbitrary and capricious, therefore the EO was struck down, even by a court that generally favors the President. _Motives_ for laws can affect whether or not they'll be struck down, too, not just legal authority.

Comment: @reirab The constitution provided checks and balances in the administration of the judicial branch precisely to control political considerations in its administration, but it is not possible to eliminate them. The constitution clearly leaves the size of the court to be specified by legislation, and the reasons for changing it do not matter. A suit by a state (or states) or members of congress would be dismissed for lack of standing, and suits by private organizations or people all the more so. Who even is the defendant? The US enjoys sovereign immunity. There's no way the suit could succeed.

Comment: @reirab the fact that the reason for ending DACA led to a judicial order preventing its ending does not follow from general legal principles, but from a specific statute that prevents the executive from acting capriciously.  The capricious nature of the purported ending of DACA was unlawful under the [Administrative Procedure Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_Procedure_Act_(United_States)).  No such argument would be available to challenge a statute passed in accordance with the constitution nor a judicial appointment made under that statute.

Comment: @phoog Hmm... I'm not sure about this particular case, but there are _lots_ of exceptions to sovereign immunity, especially when the plaintiff alleges a violation of the Constitution (at least in the case of states, sovereign immunity doesn't exist at all in such cases, though I'm not sure about the federal government.) Both states and individuals can and do sue the federal government for unconstitutional (or otherwise illegal) actions on a regular basis, though. For example, both states (e.g. Florida, et al v. HHS) and private individuals (e.g. NFIB v. Sebelius) brought cases against PPACA.